# gzip request body auto decompress

Tags: go

Doesn't Go automatically decompress gzip request body if `Content-Encoding: gzip` header is set?

e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    requestBody, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
        "accountReferenceId": "abcd",
        "transactionType":    "Deposit",
        "amount":             "100.00",
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    r, w := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        err := compressJSON(w, requestBody)
        w.CloseWithError(err)
    }()
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:7070/transactions", r)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error making request", err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
    //req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("unable to get response", err)
    }
    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("unable to read response body", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bodyBytes))
}

func compressJSON(w io.Writer, i interface{}) error {
    gz := gzip.NewWriter(w)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(gz).Encode(i); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return gz.Close()
}
```

When the server receives this request, the body content is still compressed. How can I make it auto decompress?

Comment: No, the server does not do this

Comment: I guess if you need to compress the response yourself, then it makes sense to have to decompress yourself as well.

Comment: It also depends on the `http.Transport` used to carry-out the request-response round trip; please refer to [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.DisableCompression).

Comment: Go's HTTP *client* will automatically decompress *responses*. The server does not have built-in compression support, but the middleware to add it is trivial and many versions are available in the wild.

Comment: Decompress request you mean? Its not happening in the above case., but yeah i see many middlewares for response compression